# aws s3 cp loop through lines in file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a text file (testing.txt) where each line is the path to a file I'd like to upload to S3.

testing.txt

```
homework.txt
Documents/Data/file1.txt
Photos/picture.jpg
```

I've tried this:

```
while read line
do 
    aws s3 cp $line s3://mybucket/
done < testing.txt
```

but am getting this error:

```
does not exist.d path homework.txt
does not exist.d path Documents/Data/file1.txt
does not exist.d path Photos/picture.jpg
```

I'm fairly new to this so apologies if I'm missing something or maybe this error is specific to my situation. I'm not entirely sure this should even work so pointing me in any useful direction is very much appreciated!

Comment: Are there spaces in your filenames? If so, surround $line with quotes.

Comment: first you should test your `cp` command, run it for an individual file `aws s3 cp complete_path_to_my_file_as_from_testing.txt_file s3://mybucket/`and make sure it can upload - @jbird in this case if it was an issue with space, aws would take the first part as `aws cp` command argument and will complain arguments are not correct, though its good practice to surround with quotes.

Comment: There aren't any spaces in my filenames but thanks for the suggestion. @FrédéricHenri I've been using the cp command for individual files with no issues. Does what I wrote look like it SHOULD work? At least if I know I'm on the right path it's worth looking into more.

Comment: hum .. I dont know then, maybe a bash version issue - but in my case I tested your script it was working. can you test this `while read line
do
   echo "aws s3 cp $line s3://ariba-install/"
   aws s3 cp $line s3://ariba-install/
done < file.txt` and make sure the echo is printing the expected command

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with AWS CLI. The problem is that your file has DOS format (CRLF). I've tested it, see your error messge, it says 'does not exist.d path homework.txt', which should read '...something...d path homework.txt does not exist'. I know the file exists, but not with the extra CR or LF character at the end. Try converting your file to UNIX format (use fromdos or similar tool).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for example:

```
cd ~/path/to/base-dir # This is where files are.

for f in $(cat ~/path/to/testing.txt); \
do echo "Now moving file $f"; \
aws s3 cp $f s3://mybucket/; \
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not running the command where you are supposed to .
If you are not in the correct directory then you should give absolute paths in the file so that there is no issue for bash in searching the files.